# Removing assembly: part from AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Rosyln to manipulate the `AssemblyInfo.cs` as part of a tool I'm making and I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to remove this line from a file:

```
[assembly: DeploymentLocation("\\\\someserver\\folder")]
```

I can also have this:

```
[assembly: DeploymentLocation("\\\\someserver\\folder"), DeploymentLocation("\\\\someotherserver\\folder")]
```

What I want to do is find those lines, remove them, and recreate them. Recreating them is fine, but removing them is the problem.

I can find those `DeploymentLocation` pieces like this:

```
var attr = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeSyntax>().Where(a => a.Name.ToString() == "DeploymentLocation");
```

And then I do something like this:

```
if (attr?.Any() == true)
{
    // remove existing attributes...
    syntaxRoot = syntaxRoot.RemoveNodes(attr, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
}
```

But this ends up leaving this in my file:

```
[assembly: ]
```

Which is, obviously, not what I want. How do I find the `[assembly: ]` bit and remove *that* along with the `DeploymentLocation` attribute? And obviously I don't want to remove all `[assembly: ]` lines as there's a bunch of lines that are boilerplate stuff that needs to stay.

The `assembly` bit doesn't seem to be considered a `Parent` (the `Parent`) of my tags in `attr` are the whole document. So what do I need to do to walk back to the `assembly` piece? What is that bit even called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. You need to select the `AttributeListSyntax`, which is basically the set of square brackets `[]` that contains an `AttributeSyntax` node matching what I want. Then I can remove that whole thing which would include the `AttributeTargetSyntax` (the `assembly:` part) which is a sibling to the `AttributeSyntax`

```
var attr = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeListSyntax>()
    .Where(a => a.DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeSyntax>()
    .Any(s => s.Name.ToString() == "DeploymentLocation"));
```